# I cannot understand the error in state, how to use this in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, nodemailer

I want to send emails via Nodemailer, TypeScript and NextJS. There is an error in the contact.tsx file of the state component. How to fix the error? Using setform can cause form state errors. I'm a beginner in typescript and can't find any solution for this. If anyone can solve this problem, I'd really appreciate it.

`contact.tsx` file used for page.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
export default function Contact() {

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    fname: '',
    lname: '',
    email: '',
    message: ''
  });

  const [form, setForm] = useState('')
  const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInputs((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
        }))
    }

  const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        if (inputs.fname && inputs.email && inputs.phone && inputs.message) {
            setForm({ state: 'loading' })
            try {
                const res = await fetch(`api/contact`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(inputs),
                })

                const { error } = await res.json()

                if (error) {
                    setForm({
                        state: 'error',
                        message: error,
                    })
                    return
                }

                setForm({
                    state: 'success',
                    message: 'Your message was sent successfully.',
                })
                setInputs({
                    fname: '',
                    lname: '',
                    email: '',
                    message: '',
                })
            } catch (error) {
                setForm({
                    state: 'error',
                    message: 'Something went wrong',
                })
            }
        }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmitForm(e)}>
        <input
        type="text"
        id="fname"
        value={inputs.fname}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="First Name"
        required
        />

        <input
        type="text"
        id="lname"
        value={inputs.fname}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Last Name"
        required
        />

        <input
        type="email"
        id="email"
        value={inputs.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Email"
        required
        />

        <textarea
        id="message"
        value={inputs.message}
        onChange={handleChange}
        rows={4}
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Messages"
        required
        ></textarea>

        <button
        type="submit"
        className="button"
        >
        Send inquiry
        </button>
        {form.state === 'loading' ? (
        <div>Sending....</div>
        ) : form.state === 'error' ? (
        <div>{form.message}</div>
        ) : (
        form.state === 'success' && <div>Sent successfully</div>
        )}
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any Typescript in your code, and you haven't added the error message to your question so it's not clear how you want us to help.

Comment: @Andy I'm using nextjs with TypeScript

Comment: @Andy please check the error in image.

Comment: It might be a TS _file_ but you're not using TS anywhere in that code. What is the error? Are you sure it's not a lint warning or something? Mouseover the red squiggly line to see what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some things that can be the source of your issues.

The first issue with 'setForm' in the 'useState' hook, you have intialized 'form' with an empty string  ('') as the initial state. However, later in the code, you are trying to update form using setForm with an object containing state and message properties. This can cause type errors as form is expected to be a string but you are trying to set it as an object.

You can fix this be initialze 'Form' with an object that contains the 'state' and 'message' properties:

```js
const [form, setForm] = useState({ state: '', message: '' });
```

The second issue I found was with 'handleChange': In the 'handleChange' function you are using prev as the parameter for the callback function, which implies that prev is of type

```js
React.SetStateAction<{ fname: string; lname: string; email: string; message: string; }>.
```

However, you are accessing e.target.id and e.target.value without specifying their types, which can result in type errors.

You can fix this by provide type annitations for the event object 'e' and the 'prev' parameter in the callback function like this:

```js
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    setInputs((prev: React.SetStateAction<typeof inputs>) => ({
        ...prev,
        [id]: value,
    }));
};
```

This should fix it. Make sure that you API endpoint `/api/contact` is correctly configured on your server to handle the post req and return expected response.

```js
if (inputs.fname && inputs.email && inputs.message) {
    setForm({ state: 'loading' });
    try {
        const res = await fetch(`api/contact`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(inputs),
        });
        // Rest of the code for handling response and setting state
    } catch (error) {
        setForm({
            state: 'error',
            message: 'Something went wrong',
        });
    }
}
```